# Mocking object in set

Tags: java, junit, mocking

I have the following classes:

```java
@Getter //lombok
@AllArgsConstructor //lombok
public class A {
    private Set<B> bSet;

    public void aMethod() {
        for (B b: bSet) b.bMethod();
    }
}

@AllArgsConstructor //lombok
public class B {
    public void bMethod() { 
        //do something
    }
}
```

I would like to write a test that checks if bMethod() got called for every element of bSet without caring about the Implementation of bMethod(). A unit test.

This is my JUnit test case that needs to succeed:

```java
    @Test
    public void givenAWithBSet_whenAMethodIsCalled_thenCallBMethodOnAllBs() {
        //GIVEN a with bSet
        Set<B> bSet = new HashSet<>();
        bSet.add(new B());
        bSet.add(new B());
        
        A a = new A(bSet);

        //WHEN aMethodIsCalled
        a.aMethod();

        //then call bMethod on all bs
        bSet.forEach(b -> verify(b, times(1)).bMethod());
        bSet.forEach(Mockito::verifyNoMoreInteractions);
    }
```

I tried mocking it, but was unsuccessful and need your help

Comment: It seems like you don't mock the `new B()` and instead you create an actual instance of it. Would I be correct in this observation? If I am correct, then it's no surprising it doesn't behave exactly according to test expectation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to just verify that each `B` in your `Set` has its `bMethod` invoked, you can set up your test something like this:

```
@Test
public void givenAWithBSet_whenAMethodIsCalled_thenCallBMethodOnAllBs() {
    Set<B> bSet = new HashSet<>();
    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
        bSet.add(Mockito.mock(B.class));
    }

    A a = new A(bSet);

    a.aMethod();

    for (B b : a.getBSet()) {
        verify(b).bMethod();
    }
}
```

It will verify that `bMethod` was called on each of the mocks.  It'd be nice to use the same mock, but as you're using a `Set` and the mock uses the identity function for equality, you'll need to create multiples.